WPF application allocates huge number of TimerQueueTimer objects
I've got WPF application built with .NET 8, at some point it suddenly spiked both on CPU and memory. I managed to capture memory snapshot and it seems like there are lots of TimerQueueTimer objects allocated, not sure where did they come from.
Here's a screenshot:

Did anyone have anything like that? I've seen it here: Too many TimerQueueTimer objects getting allocated and consuming high memory
But that was an ASP.NET application and problem was solved by updating to ASP.NET Core, while mine is WPF.
Application was running fine for ~1 day, but suddenly spiked on CPU and memory consumption. It should normally consume no more ~100M of managed memory.

I found both AnonymousSafeObserver and ConcurrencyAbstractionLayerImpl belong to reactive extensions, do you have any ideas?

Are you sure you are disposing everything that needs to be disposed? That all event handlers are unregistered if needed? That is typically good places to start investigating leaks. WPF is a bit special since most objects cannot be disposed, but you may still need to do some cleanup in some cases. If this is timer related it is probably a good idea to start with checking any code that uses timers, indirectly or directly.

I also encounter the same Issue, and found out that I have a loop as follow
while (true) {
   var cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
   cancelSource.CancelAfter(50);
   var item = queue.Take(cancelSource.Token);
   if (!state.isValid(item)){
      queue.Add(item);
   }
} 

And Since the if condition is always hit, it create new
CancellationTokenSource  and in cancelSource.CancelAfter(50) it will create TimerQueueTimer Object.
